# How to add items to a datagrid at runtime in flex4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

My UserInfromation form contains two input fields username,location(city) and one radio button as gender and two buttons add and reset.when I click on add button that data will be added in datagrid at runtime.
I am unable to reproduce how will i do this.
can anyone help me on this with example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app (with code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            protected function addBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var obj:Object = new Object();
                obj.userName = userNameTI.text;
                obj.location = locationTI.text;
                ac.addItem(obj);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Form width="100%">
        <mx:FormItem label="UserName:">
            <s:TextInput id="userNameTI"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Location:">
            <s:TextInput id="locationTI"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
    <s:Button id="addBtn" label="Add" click="addBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" dataProvider="{ac}"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Couple of things are left for you as an exercise :)